# How to let the UIScroll view only horizontal and vertical scroll only?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

For example, I have 9 grids. It order like this:

`7 8 9`

`4 5 6`

`1 2 3`

If I am in the position `5`, the user can now scroll to `3` using one scroll. But I would like to limit they scroll to `6` only, then go to `3` or scroll to `2`, and then `3`. Which not allow them scroll to `3` only.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own logic + These below three properties of UIScrollview will help you to acheive your goal.

```
yourScroller.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
yourScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
[yourScroller scrollRectToVisible:yourFrame animated:YES];
```

**ExampleCode:**

```
-(void)changeAndIncrementBottomScrollerPage{

    //maximum number of pages is 3
    if (3 != UpAndDownPager.currentPage) {      

        int page = UpAndDownPager.currentPage + 1;
        CGRect frame = scroller.frame;  
        frame.origin.y  = frame.size.height * page;

        if (0 != sidePager.currentPage) {

            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (sidePager.currentPage);
        }

        [yourScroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];      
        UpAndDownPager.currentPage = UpAndDownPager.currentPage + 1;    

    }
}
```